# How to sort Banshee by track order?

Tags: banshee, music, multimedia

I have several playlists containing only one artist, but multiple albums by that artist. I would like to sort these playlists so that the albums are grouped together and ordered by track number.

For some reason, clicking on the columns does not sort them. It's like the column headers are static and can't be clicked. I think manual sorting is turned on, but I don't know how to turn it off.

I know there are other players, but I really love the integration with Unity, and don't want to give it up.